# Windows powershell error when modifying windows service parameter

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I am trying to update one of the parameters of Windows Service (kubelet) by using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster-windows#image_pull_errors)

```
1.  $regkey = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\kubelet"
2.  $name = "ImagePath"
3.  $(reg query ${regkey} /v ${name} | Out-String) -match "(?s)${name}.*(C:.*kubelet\.exe.*)"
4.  $kubelet_cmd = $Matches[1] -replace "--image-pull-progress-deadline=.* ","" -replace "\r\n"," "
5.  reg add ${regkey} /f /v ${name} /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "${kubelet_cmd} --image-pull-progress-deadline=40m "
```

**Step #3 output**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $(reg query ${regkey} /v ${name} | Out-String) -match "(?s)${name}.*(C:.*kubelet\.exe.*)"
True
```

**Output of Steps 4 and 5**

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $kubelet_cmd = $Matches[1] -replace "--image-pull-progress-deadline=.* ","" -replace "\r\n"," "

PS C:\Users\Administrator> reg add ${regkey} /f /v ${name} /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "${kubelet_cmd} --image-pull-progress-deadline=40m "
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.
```

I am not sure which part of **reg add** is causing this error.  Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong

**EDIT**

Output of $kubelet_cmd is given below

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator>   echo $kubelet_cmd
C:\ProgramData\Kubernetes\kubernetes\node\bin\kubelet.exe --windows-service --v=6 --log-dir=C:\ProgramData\Kubernetes\logs\kubelet --cert-dir=C:\var\lib\kubelet\pki --cni-bin-dir=C:\ProgramData\Kubernetes\cni --cni-conf-dir=C:\ProgramData\Kubernetes\cni\config --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --hostname-override=WIN --pod-infra-container-image=mcr.microsoft.com/k8s/core/pause:1.2.0 --enable-debugging-handlers  --cgroups-per-qos=false --enforce-node-allocatable="" --logtostderr=false --network-plugin=cni --resolv-conf="" --cluster-dns="10.96.0.10" --cluster-domain=cluster.local --feature-gates=
```

It appears some of the attributes have double-quotes which is causing the issue.  But, not sure how to overcome this when executing Step #5

Comment: You're overcomplicating this... Have you considered the `Set-Service` cmdlet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the steps by editing Windows registry

1. Opened Windows registry
2. Navigated to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\kubelet` hive
3. Right-click --> Modify on attribute `ImagePath` (on the right pane)
4. Added the parameter `--image-pull-progress-deadline=50m`
5. Restarted `kubelet` service using services.msc